# My stylesheet won't be applied for the specified width using media queries

Tags: css

I have four main stylesheets and another two stylesheets for jQuery UI and Flexslider. One for reset stylesheet, one for main stylesheet and another two for media queries. The problem is that the stylesheet with (max-width:767px) won't be applied while the main stylesheet and the stylesheet for the width between 768px to 1259px work well.

Here is my markup

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1259px)" href="css/responsive_768-1259.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen and (max-width:767px)" href="css/responsive_xxx-767.css" />

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/ui-  lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/FlexSlider-version-2.2/flexslider.css" />
```

So, please help me figure out what's wrong at this point and how can I make the stylesheet with (max-width:767px) work.

Note that the main stylesheet `style.css` is applied for the width more than 1260px which is the width of my main container.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could combine both the css ie. responsive_768-1259.css and responsive_xxx-767.css into one say responsive.css

Your responsive.css should contain the following.

```
@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:1280px){
/*-----All of your responsive_768-1259.css goes here---*/
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
/*-----All of your responsive_xxx-767.css goes here---*/
}
```